# When filtering content of 2 models together getting - 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'?

Tags: python, django-filter

I usually display filter options by one model.But now I have to allow to filter by the content of 2 models.

```
class Lease(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    is_notrenewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    is_terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class LeaseConditions(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    lease = models.ForeignKey(Lease)
    increase  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    is_terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    not_terminated_active_objects = NotTerminatedActiveManager()
```

So I added 2nd model to my filter

```
class LeaseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Lease,LeaseConditions
        fields = ['is_notrenewed', 'unit',
        'is_terminated', 'start_date']
```

but getting error now

> 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

What could be the problem?

Trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/lease/list/?is_notrenewed=1&unit=&is_terminated=1

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'concurrency',
 'registration',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_filters',
 'common',
 'client',
 'lease',
 'unit')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  402.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\rentout\rentout\urls.py" in <module>
  11.     url(r'^lease/', include('lease.urls')),
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
  33.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\rentout\lease\urls.py" in <module>
  2. from lease import views 
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\rentout\lease\views.py" in <module>
  59. class LeaseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py" in __new__
  181.             filters = new_class.filters_for_model(opts.model, opts)
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py" in filters_for_model
  456.             cls.filter_for_reverse_field
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py" in filters_for_model
  78.         field = get_model_field(model, f)
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django_filters\utils.py" in get_model_field
  72.     opts = model._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /lease/list/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: It looks like I was going the wrong path 
http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#declaring-filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model` property must be a model, not a tuple of models - you are specifying two models for an object that accepts only one. For filtering based on related objects, you can do it like this:

```
class LeaseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = LeaseConditions
        fields = ['lease__is_notrenewed', 'lease__unit', 'is_terminated', 'start_date']
```